# Parse list as argument to a custom serializer procedure

Tags: xml, vb.net, list, serialization

I would like to make a procedure which serialize a LIST specified as an argument. But I cannot figure out how to specify the **GetType(List(of MyClass))** when MyClass is parsed by argument. I cannot "hard-code" MyClass in the procedure as I must use this serializer-procedure with different classes.

```
Sub Main
   Dim MyList As New List(Of NameClass)
   MyList.Add(New NameClass("Thomas")
   MyList.Add(New NameClass("Michael")
   List_To_XMLFile(MyList, NameClass, "c:\temp\file.xml")
End sub

Sub List_To_XMLFile(MyList As List(Of Object), ListOfCObj As Object, Path As String)
    Dim ser As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of ListOfObject)))
    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(Path, FileMode.Create)
    ser.Serialize(fs, MyList)
    fs.Close()
End Sub

Public Class NameClass
    Property Name As String
    Sub New()
    End Sub
    Sub New(Name As String)
        Me.Name = Name
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object knows its type, so if you pass the object don't need to pass the type.

```
Sub List_To_XMLFile(Of T)(MyList As List(Of T), Path As String)
    Dim ser As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(MyList.GetType())
    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(Path, FileMode.Create)
    ser.Serialize(fs, MyList)
    fs.Close()
End Sub
```

And call the procedure with

```
List_To_XMLFile(MyList, "c:\temp\file.xml")
```

Note that since I'm using generic type, the method can be called passing `New List(Of NameClass)`, `New List(Of OtherClass)`, etc. So that `T` takes the type.

Comment: But I cannot "hard code" NameClass in the argument. The whole idea is you can reuse the procedure with different lists and classes, so it has to be parsed be a reference/variable?

Comment: then we can use generic type T

Comment: It works perfectly! I'm afraid it would have taken med weeks or month reading MSDN and Google to end up with that solution myself, perhaps ever, haha. I'm very grateful :-) :-)

Comment: And to set the name of the root element:
Dim ser As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(MyList.GetType(),New XmlRootAttribute("MyRoot"))
If anyone like to get rid of the ArrayOfClassName